# What regexp is used with sed to reorder words on a line

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I wish to transpose some words in a line using output from one command piped to another.  Given these lines of output:

```
v4l_compat  1.18.0  Apr 20  2020
vim 8.2.0491_1  Apr 20  2020
vsftpd-ssl  3.0.3_2 Apr 20  2020
webcamd 5.7.1.1 Apr 20  2020
webcamoid   8.7.1   Apr 20  2020
wireshark   3.2.3   Apr 20  2020
```

I want to produce:

```
2020-Apr-20 v4l_compat 1.18.0
2020-Apr-20 vim 8.2.0491_1
2020-Apr-20 vsftpd-ssl 3.0.3_2  
2020-Apr-20 webcamd 5.7.1.1
2020-Apr-20 webcamoid 8.7.1
2020-Apr-20 wireshark 3.2.3
```

I have tried several variations of this regex to reorder the capture groups:

```
 echo 'vsftpd-ssl  3.0.3_2 Apr 20  2020' | sed -E 's/([\-\.|\d|\w]+\b)/\5-\3-\4 \1 \2/'
 sed: 1: "s/([\-\.|\d|\w]+\b)/\5- ...": \5 not defined in the RE
```

But I am never able to obtain any more capture groups than the entire string itself

```
 echo 'vsftpd-ssl  3.0.3_2 Apr 20  2020' | sed -E 's/([\-\.|\d|\w]+\b)/\1/'
 vsftpd-ssl  3.0.3_2 Apr 20  2020
```

However, when I test the regex at Rubular using 'py37-evdev    0.8.1_1    Jan    9    2020' I get this result:

```
Match 1
1.  py37-evdev
Match 2
1.  0.8.1_1
Match 3
1.  Jan
Match 4
1.  9
Match 5
1.  2020
```

And if I do the same thing at regex101.com I get this result:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-10    py37-evdev
Group 1.    0-10    py37-evdev
Match 2
Full match  11-18   0.8.1_1
Group 1.    11-18   0.8.1_1
Match 3
Full match  19-22   Jan
Group 1.    19-22   Jan
Match 4
Full match  23-24   9
Group 1.    23-24   9
Match 5
Full match  25-29   2020
Group 1.    25-29   2020
```

I can see that regex101 is only returning one group with matches inside the group but I do not see what it is that I am doing wrong such that I do not get 5 groups instead.  I also cannot seem to get the match groups to restart when the line changes.

What do I have to do to get this to work?

Comment: With awk: `awk '{print $5 "-" $3 "-" $4,$1,$2}'`

Comment: sed doesn't support `\d` and `\w` doesn't work inside character class and `|` inside character class will match it literally, see also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y).. sites like regex101 are not useful for cli tools because regex syntax/feature vary significantly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ s="v4l_compat  1.18.0  Apr 20  2020
vim 8.2.0491_1  Apr 20  2020
vsftpd-ssl  3.0.3_2 Apr 20  2020
webcamd 5.7.1.1 Apr 20  2020
webcamoid   8.7.1   Apr 20  2020
wireshark   3.2.3   Apr 20  2020"
```

Sure is easy with `awk`:

```
$ echo "$s" | awk '{printf "%s-%s-%s %s %s\n", $5,$3,$4,$1,$2}'
```

Prints:

```
2020-Apr-20 v4l_compat 1.18.0
2020-Apr-20 vim 8.2.0491_1
2020-Apr-20 vsftpd-ssl 3.0.3_2
2020-Apr-20 webcamd 5.7.1.1
2020-Apr-20 webcamoid 8.7.1
2020-Apr-20 wireshark 3.2.3
```

If you *want* `sed` you could do:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)/\5-\3-\4 \1 \2/'

# same output...
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a difficult match on the first part.

```
echo "py37-evdev 0.8.1_1 Jan 9 2020" | sed -r 's/(.*) (\w+)[ ]+(\w+)[ ]+(\w+)/\2-\3-\4 \1/'
```